# How to I use Python PIL to produce a 1000x1000 thumbnail without distorting the image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to export out 1000x1000 thumbnails of images in Python PIL without distorting the original images.

This code works if the original image has dimensions exceeding 1000x1000.

```
(width, height) = img.size
left = int((width - 1000)/2)
right = left + 1000
new_img = img.crop((left, 0, right, height))
new_img = new_img.resize((1000,1000))
```

However, if the images have dimensions below this, such as 800 x 400, they become stretched out and distorted.

Comment: Please try to improve your question - it is not very clear what you want. What result do you expect if the input image is 500px wide and 100px tall? What if the input image is 100px wide by 500px tall?

Comment: I've tried to improve my question. In that example, the image would need to be enlarged and then cropped.

Comment: I gave 2 examples - which one are you referring to please? Also, you say it should be enlarged and cropped - enlarged to what size and which part cropped?

Comment: In the first, enlarged to 5000 wide and 1000 tall then cropped evenly from left and right so it's a 1000x1000 image.

In the second, enlarged to 1000 wide and 5000 tall then cropped evenly from left and right so it's a 1000x1000 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, whatever be the size of the image, it needs to be cropped to a 1000x1000 image.

One way to do this is by first cropping the image into a square and then resizing it to 1000x1000.

```
(width, height) = img.size
if width < height: # if width is smaller than height, crop height
    h = int((height - width)/2)
    new_img = img.crop((0, h, width, width+h))
else: # if height is smaller than width, crop width
    w = int((width - height)/2)
    new_img = img.crop((w, 0, height+w, height))
# resize to required size
new_img = new_img.resize((1000,1000))
```

It is more efficient to crop first and then enlarge than to enlarge first and then crop. This is because in the second case, you are doing image operations (i.e, cropping) on a larger image which uses more resources (CPU, RAM, etc) than cropping smaller images. If you're working on large number of images this could result considerable difference in processing time.